# How can I put element beside another? (Android)

Tags: android, width, screen, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to put the `atendenteBalaoProdutoValor` element beside the `atendenteBalaoProdutoNome`, for this. I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/layoutAtendenteBalao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+atendente/rltAtendenteBalao">

    <TextView
        style="@style/campoAtendenteBalaoTexto"
        android:id="@+atendente/txtTexto"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/atendenteBalaoVO"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+atendente/rltAtendenteBalaoVO">"

        <TextView
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOTexto1"
            android:id="@+atendente/txtAtendenteBalaoVOTexto1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOTextoQuantidadeTexto2">"

            <EditText
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOQuantidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtAtendenteBalaoVOQuantidade"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOTexto2"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtAtendenteBalaoVOTexto2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOMais"
            android:id="@+atendente/btnAtendenteBalaoVOMais"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoVOMenos"
            android:id="@+atendente/btnAtendenteBalaoVOMenos"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/atendenteBalaoProduto"
        android:id="@+atendente/lnrProduto">

        <TextView
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoNome"
            android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoNome"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProduto1"
            android:id="@+atendente/lnrAtendenteBalaoProduto1">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoImagem"
                android:id="@+atendente/imgProduto"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoDescricao"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoDescricao"/>

        </LinearLayout>        

        <TextView
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoValor"
            android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoValor"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/atendenteBalaoProduto2"
            android:id="@+atendente/lnrProdutoQuantidade"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoRotuloQuantidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoQuantidadeRotulo" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoQuantidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoQuantidade"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:digits="0123456789,." 
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

            <TextView
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoUnidade"
                android:id="@+atendente/txtProdutoUnidade"/>

            <Button
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoMenosMais"
                android:id="@+atendente/btnQtdeMenos"
                android:text="-" />

            <Button
                style="@style/atendenteBalaoProdutoMenosMais"
                android:id="@+atendente/btnQtdeMais"
                android:text="+" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the **styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoNome">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">13dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="atendenteBalaoProdutoValor">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

But it is like this:
[image]

Instead of:

[image]

I tried to put `RelativeLayout` on `atendenteBalaoProduto` and set the values `android:layout_alignParentLeft`,`android:layout_toLeftOf`,`android:layout_alignParentRight` on `atendenteBalaoProdutoNome` and `atendenteBalaoProdutoValor` elements, but it also haven't worked.

Comment: You should include the styles, because it is impossible to see which properties are being set.

Comment: @kevinpelgrims Now the styles is included